# How to delete specific name pattern directories in temp folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, temp

I need to write a windows bat program to delete particular folders with naming pattern scoped_dir45666,scoped_dir45667 ...so on (for example)(including contents) 
with batch program. For that I am using below code:

```
@echo off
Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F 
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
cd /D %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

but its deleting everything under %temp% causing system issues...(its screwing some os files also I guess)

I need to delete all directories names starting with scoped_dirxxxxx (scoped_dir*) under %temp% directory of my user can some one advise how to modify above code to delete only folders name starting with scoped_dir in %temp% folder

Comment: You say _"it is deleting everything under `%temp%`"_. Well, it will because you tell it to remove all directories and ontop of that you do `del /f /q *` in that dir as well..

Comment: Did you try anything on your own? when `*` matches all directories, how do you think the should pattern look like to match files beginning with `scoped_dir` only? have you tried `scoped_dir*`?

Comment: Just a note that there's no need to `CD` into the directory first, just use `@For /D %%A In ("%TEMP%\scoped_dir*") Do @RD /S/Q "%%A"`.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, I am trying to simulate before I actually delete. however including echo in Do Echo @RD /S/Q "%%A " , cmd is flashing and going...I wanted to at least echo before i delete, so i can be sure what i am deleting..

Comment: @asp, use `@For /D %%A In ("%TEMP%\scoped_dir*") Do @Echo(RD /S/Q "%%A"`, then temporarily add another line beneath it, `@Pause`, this will leave the window open until you follow the instruction…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the prefix in front of the wildcard:

```
for /d %%D in (scoped_dir*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
```

If you only want to delete these directories, you should also get rid of the last line `del /f /q *` as it will delete all files on the root level of your `%TEMP%` directory.

Comment: Yes, i guess that is the problem for that del command its screwing something.. yes, I want to delete only scoped directories `@echo off
Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F 
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
cd /D %temp%
for /d %%D in (scoped_dir*) do rd /s /q "%%D"` so are these enough, I removed that last line

Comment: @asp Cool. Note that you still have the un-prefixed wildcard `*` in your comment above...

Comment: sorry, i just edited now i am gonna try now...now updated statement should work right ? and also do i need to mention full path of %temp% or will it take automatically..I little bit cautious, as i my previous attempt screwed something :)

Comment: @asp Yep! It will only delete the directories whose names start with `scoped_dir`. You are `CD`ing into `%TEMP%` before, so no need to mention it again with this script. Understand you're cautious - Tip: For testing your script, replace `rd /s /q "%%D"` with `ECHO rd /s /q "%%D"` so you can see what would be executed. If you're confident with that, remove the `ECHO` again to "activate" the script.

Comment: hi i ran below script as per suggestion as test `Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F 
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
cd /D %temp%
for /d %%D in (scoped_dir*) do ECHO rd /s /q "%%D"` i pasted into notpead, saved it as a bat file, and ran it, cmd flashed and gone, some how it did not allow to see output ..any suggestion

Comment: @asp Add `PAUSE` at the end of the script.

Comment: thank you at last it worked..only difference I see now under Temp folder called 1 and i find scoped directories under it. though may be windows creates temp folder with number for each session i guess